# In android how to get rid of screen rendering issues

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

In android how to get rid of this type screen rendering problem, am getting this rendering problem looks like color noise am getting this only on lollipop devices rest of devices is working fine.

in the below screen the activity Just getting data from asyncTask and set to parallax listview.

[image: Sample Screen Shot]

Comment: Is this an emulator screeenshot?

Comment: mobile moto g 2nd gen device screeenshot

Comment: How long does it last? Just until the data is loaded?

Comment: appears just few seconds when the activity launched.

Comment: Its a bug in lollipop OS.

Comment: how to fix this one.